# Should tone sandhi be written in pinyin?

Tags: pinyin, tones, writing, sandhi

> Tone sandhi is a phonological change occurring in tonal languages, in
>   which the tones assigned to individual words or morphemes change based
>   on the pronunciation of adjacent words or morphemes.

For example `不是`:

- the original tone for each character is: **bù shì** (4 4)
- After tone sandhi: **bú shì** (2 4)

Some say that it can be confusing to write it as if it is written, it would be confusing to know what the original tone is supposed to be.

Is there an standard practice to address this?

Comment: there also is the matter of tone changes to other than neutral occurring on  一、七 depending on tone on the following character, in which case nevertheless the original tone mark is preserved (discussed at this site before)

Comment: Just one note. Neutral tone is different. Neutral tone has been clearly addressed in dictionary, while tone sandhi is not addressed in any formal dictionaries.

Comment: exactly, tone sandhi refers to 33 changing to 23, besides tone change on 一／七 there also is on 不，this all has been discussed before, in fact below answer has been given before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tone Sandi rule should merely apply to spoken. In written, you should always put original tones in any forms of exams except that those exams are testing the rule itself.

In fact, I doubt most of natives are aware of the existence of Tone Sandi indeed. But they do apply the rule naturally in practice. I suggest you study by phrase, not by character. That way you will know how each character will be used and the way to pronounce in practice.

Comment: Never realize that. In fact, I never thought too much about neutral tone, though I know it is 轻声.

Answer (score 2):

Standard practice is not to change the tone diacritics to represent tone sandhi. So `bù shì` keeps the fourth tone on `bù` in spite of the pronunciation as `bú shì`. The same applies to the tones on 一 / yī, even though some learners dictionaries diverge from this rule. The rule also applies to third-tone sandhi.

See for example [Tone change rules](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/pronunciation/Tone_change_rules) in the Chinese Pronunciation Wiki.